# Make multitple controlled material-ui tooltips open one at the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I have a component where i use a few other componentes. I used to have the problem when a select menu was open, the tooltip overlaps the menu and don't stop showing. Now that i have make the Tooltip 'controlled' when i hover on one component it shows all the tooltips, and when click in one stop appearing (this is what i want but on hover one at the same time). This is how it looks:
[image]

I have my tooltip like this outside the function of the component im working on:

```
function Tooltip(props) {
 const classes = tooltipStyles();
 return <TooltipBase placement="bottom" classes={classes} {...props} />;
}
```

And this is how it looks in every component i mannage inside the main component:

```
<Tooltip title="Estatus" open={openTooltip}>
          <div
            onMouseEnter={() => {
              setOpenTooltip(true);
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              setOpenTooltip(false);
            }}
          >
            <Chip
              small
              onIconClicked={null}
              label="Por hacer"
              avatarProps={{
                size: 'extraSmall',
                backgroundColor: '#F57C00',
                icon: null,
              }}
              isDropdown
              onChipClicked={handleOpen}
              withPopover
              popoverKey="status"
              popoverOpen={chipStatusOpen}
              popOverContent={PopupStatus}
              onPopoverClose={handleClose}
            />
            <PopupFilters
              anchorEl={anchorElPopupFilters}
              onClose={() => setAnchorElPopupFilters(null)}
            />
          </div>
        </Tooltip>
```

These are the functions im using to open/close the tooltips an select/popups

```
const handleClose = () => {
setChipStatus(false);
setAnchorEl(null);
};
   const handleOpen = () => {
   setChipStatus(true);
   setOpenTooltip(false);
 };
```

And the useStates that i use to make it work

```
const [chipStatusOpen, setChipStatus] = useState(false);
const [openTooltip, setOpenTooltip] = useState(false);
```

I want to open one at a time. How can i achieve that? What am i doing wrong?